# Convergence of the series $\frac{1} {n} \sin(nx) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I've been trying to work out the solution to this problem.
Consider $\forall x \in \mathbb R $ the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1} {n} \sin(nx) $$ Find the values of $x$ for which the series converge (pointwise, uniformly or absolutely).

My attempt:

It is obvious that for every $x \in \mathbb R $, we have $ \vert \sin(nx) \vert \le 1$, and if we take the points $x=\frac{\pi} {2n}$ our series is exactly the harmonic series and it doesn't pass the Weierstrass M-test. So our series is not absolutely and uniformly convergent (at one time).

Then if we take the points $x=k\pi, k \in \mathbb Z$, our series converges to 0, very easily.

For the other values of $x$, I tried using other common tests, such as *ratio* and *root* test (I get the inconclusive 1), and figuring out useful bounds for the sequence, but didn't succeed. I suspect it converges, but I don't know how to go on.

Am I mistaken? Are there any other tests?

Comment: Do you know Dirichlet's criterion?

Comment: alternatively to remember some specific criterion you can use [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) to solve many questions about convergence or divergence of series. Indeed Dirichlet's criterion is just an application of summation by parts

Comment: It also converges, as an alternating series if $x\equiv\frac\pi 2\mod\pi$.

Comment: What constant I can use to bound the absolute value of the partial sums of $sin(nx)$?

Comment: The constant depends on $x$. So the bound is a function of $x$ (working for all upper limits $k$ of the partial sums) rather than a constant.

Comment: I get it. Do you think it might be useful to work out an explicit expression for it?